# How to avoid the ROOT Element when parsing from XML to JSON in C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml, json, json.net

I am trying to create a JSON from an xml using JSON.NET

```
XmlDocument docPerson = new XmlDocument();
docPerson.LoadXml(xmlPerson); //xmlPerson is the xml from above
JObject personDefinition = JObject.Parse(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(docPerson));
Tasks.personDefinition = personDefinition["personDefinition"];
```

OUTPUT JSON

```
"person":{"person":[{"personId":"1","firstName":"Name1","lastName":"lastName1"},                  {"personId":"3","firstName":"Name2","lastName":"lastName2"}]}
```

I don't need the outer person and just need the following json

REQUIRED JSON

```
"person":[{"personId":"1","firstName":"1","lastName":"Weight"},{"personId":"3","firstName":"4","lastName":"Pulse Ox"}]}
```

I have tried using the .first method however it is throwing an error. Can anyone suggest on how to strip the root  from the output json

Comment: You could just remove that part of the string.

Comment: Does your xml have a person root node and then a person node inside it? if that is the case you could try by removing the root element docPerson.LoadXml(docPerson.FirstChild.InnerXml);

Comment: Would be helpful if we´d see the XML that you´re trying to parse

Comment: The XML is string xml = "<PersonDefinition><Person><name>Nicolas</name><age>22</age></Person><Person><name>Pankaj</name><age>25</age></Person></PersonDefinition>"

Answer (score 28, accepted):

JSON.Net has a `SerializeXmlNode()` method that can do exactly what you want.  Simply pass `true` to the `omitRootObject` parameter.
Observe:

```
string xmlPerson = @"<PersonDefinition><Person><name>Nicolas</name><age>22</age></Person><Person><name>Pankaj</name><age>25</age></Person></PersonDefinition>";
XmlDocument docPerson = new XmlDocument();
docPerson.LoadXml(xmlPerson);
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(docPerson, Formatting.None, true);
Console.WriteLine(json);
```

Output:

```
{"Person":[{"name":"Nicolas","age":"22"},{"name":"Pankaj","age":"25"}]}
```

Comment: how can i wrap {"Person":[{"name":"Nicolas","age":"22"},{"name":"Pankaj","age":"25"}]} into single person attribute in xml, i want other way around.

Comment: @cracker Comments are not the appropriate place to ask new questions.  If you need help, [Ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).  You can include [a link back to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19311332) to provide context.

Answer (score 0):

```
string xml = "<PersonDefinition><Person><name>Nicolas</name><age>22</age></Person><Person><name>Pankaj</name><age>25</age></Person></PersonDefinition>";

XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Person[]), new XmlRootAttribute("PersonDefinition"));
JavaScriptSerializer jsonSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(xml))
{
    Person[] people = xmlSerializer.Deserialize(reader) as Person[];
    string json = jsonSerializer.Serialize(new Person());
}
```

Use some kind of variation of this.

Comment: The xml you have entered is correct but there are multiple Person inside PersonDefinition string xml = "<PersonDefinition><Person><name>Nicolas</name><age>22</age></Person><Person><name>Pankaj</name><age>25</age></Person></PersonDefinition>"

Comment: I am not able to resolve the JavaScriptSerializer namespace. My project is .Net 4.0 WebAPI project. I know it needs System.Web.Script.Serialization; which is not available in my project

Comment: I am able to resolve the JavaScriptSerializer namespace however I don't have a Person class defined as the XML is variable and can contain unknown objects but in the same format. I need to be able to convert the XML into JSON in the same format.

Comment: @user2515186 You don't need a different serializer.  JSON.Net already does what you want.  You just need to use a different method.  See my answer.